# Is it possible to set up a page using GitHub Pages that will source files from my GitHub repo?

Tags: git, deployment, github, github-pages

I'd like to make it so that a regular push on my GitHub repo will update the code on the webpage so that I can immediately test it anywhere with my mobile devices (I've been relying on `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, which is rubbish. I mean it's neat, but clearly was not designed to account for the sleepy HTTP connections produced by my mobile devices.

Can this be done using some sort of `git` thing where I can get a second remote repo to auto-pull changes from another repo? Or something?

Is this what the `gh-pages` branch is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gh-pages branch allows you to update your html files locally and push it to a github web server that serves static content on the web from `http://youruser.github.com/yourproject`.

There are automatic tools offered by github to bootstrap a website from the README.md (markdown format, the same used here to format Q & A) like the [automatic generator](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator), or a site+blog static site generator using [Jekill](http://tom.preston-werner.com/jekyll/). On github there are [several other alternatives](https://github.com/search?q=static%20site%20generator) that can work with gh-pages.

Comment: cool. looks like i can just work on my JS library in the gh-pages branch as my working branch then. Then merge my work onto master whenever I feel like it.

Comment: the first time you push, it can take a little bit longer, since some setup has to be made. After then, the process is almost instantaneous

Answer (score 0):

Oooh I think it's this.

http://xlson.com/2010/11/09/getting-started-with-github-pages.html

It's probably this. Sounds like fun.